# MSAL browser dialog close

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, dialog, azure-ad-msal

I have a problem when I close the sign in Dialog from **msal** with the right upper close button (red x), which I get from the call of `AcquireTokenAsync(scope)`.

The problem is, I get a valid result from `AcquireToken`, the result is the same which i get from a login before.

Detail:
I sign in with an account from active directory **b2c.** works. Then log out, clear cookies and token cache also delete user from `PublicClientApplication.Users`. Log in again, The `AcquireTokenSilent` throws a `MsalUiRequiredException` as expected, with `AcquireToken` the `SignIn`-Dialog opens, i can now choose the account which I signed in before, (but I cleared all, strange), when i then remove the account (the three dots, in the right upper corner from the login-dialog) and say then cancel, I get null as result, but when closing the sign in dialog, I get the same result as when i normal sign in.

Is this a normal behaviour, because the account from last login is somewhere saved and i have to remove them, or miss I something else?

I use the MSAL 1.1.0-preview version, in an Desktop WPF app.
Also with an own TokenCache, but these deletes every sign out the saved information.

thanks
dstreissi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the **msal** works as expected, I used the code sample from [Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2/tree/master/active-directory-wpf-nodejs-webapi-v2). There is a `try-catch` around the `AcquireToken`. These `catch a MsalException`. If you cancel, the `AcquireToken` throws a `MsalException`. I catched it and newer throw it again.

For the same `AuthenticationResult`, I forgot to reset it.

So `msal 1.1.0-preview` works fine for me now.